# Insert bounded code snippets to generated Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a bounded script to a spreadsheet 'A' that generates a new spreadsheet 'N' for each name I have in a list in spreadsheet 'A'. I would like to add a bounded script to each spreadhsheet 'N' such as:

```js
function onEdit() {
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var row = sh.getActiveCell().getRowIndex();
  var col = sh.getActiveCell().getColumn();
  Logger.log(row + " " + col);
  if (row == 3 && col == 1)
  {
    var value = sh.getActiveCell().getValue();
    if (value == "I")
    {
      var today = formatDate(new Date());
      var newdate = new Date(today);
  
      newdate.setDate(newdate.getDate() + 15);
      
      var dd = newdate.getDate();
      var mm = newdate.getMonth() + 1;
      var y = newdate.getFullYear();
  
      var someFormattedDate = mm + '/' + dd + '/' + y;
      Logger.log(someFormattedDate);
      sh.getRange(row, 3).setValue(someFormattedDate);
    }
  }
}
  
function formatDate(date) 
{
    return (date.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + date.getDate() + '/' + date.getFullYear();
}
```

I have tried to do that by inserting formulas but the TODAY() function always updates the cell.

Any ideas? Is it possible to add bounded snippet of code to a google spreadsheet created programmatically with google apps scripts?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I found what I was looking for with SriptApp Class with the [SpreadsheetTriggerBuilder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/spreadsheet-trigger-builder)